# ANOVA analysis?

Tags: anova, spss, binary-data

I need some help since I'm not that good with statistics.

I have to perform a study to know whether different groups of people are willing to buy a product. 
I've shown 6 different scenarios, thus I have 6 groups of people. A certain number of those people bought the product, while the other didn't.
Basically now I have 1000 records, each record represents a person, which is part of a group and did (or did not) buy the product.
I was asked to perform an anova analysis.

I have two main questions: is the anova the best method? I'm asking since the dependent variable (the purchase) is binary.

Second question, I've been trying to run ANOVA in SPSS, the output shows sum of squares = 1,772 between groups, and 81 within groups. 
As far as I know, the DF are ok, since they represent the number of groups-1 and the number of observation between groups -1 (so since I have 1071 observation and 6 group the DF within group is 1065). 
The mean squares are 0.354 and 0.77, the F value is 4.632. The sig. is .000.
Since I've never done something similar, can these data be considered 'normal', in other words, is the study significant?

Comment: Since you are analyzing a 2-by-6 contingency table, chi-square test is more appropriate. ANOVA would have been of choice for your analysis if the dependent variable (DV) were continuous and hence if your interest were to compare the mean of the DV across the six groups.

Comment: Thanks. That's exaclty the reason why I was wondering whether ANOVA was fine. However I did the chi-square (following this guide: https://statistics.laerd.com/spss-tutorials/chi-square-test-for-association-using-spss-statistics.php) and Pearson Chi-square asymp. sig is still 0. 
In the symmetric measures table, I got value = .146 and sig. = .000. 
Is there a way, like an online lecture, that could help me with the interpretation (or at least a fixed benchmark beside the pvalue to know if the data are significant) ? I'm feeling the stupidest girl on earth!

Comment: In SPSS output if the p-value is less than one-thousandth, it is reported as .000. So it doesn't necessarily mean zero. In such instances you can report the p-value as `p<0.001`. In Chi-square test, we decide whether there is statistical significance using p-values (no other 'fixed benchmark' which I know of). I didn't understand what you mean by 'symmetric measures table.' But generally, in Chi-square test there is no issue of symmetry. The Chi-square distribution is not a symmetric distribution (it begins from zero and extends indefinitely to the right).

Comment: For additional help you can look at www.statstutor.ac.uk/resources/uploaded/coventrychisquared.pdf and www.ucdenver.edu/academics/colleges/nursing/.../ChiSquareHowTo.pdf.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I completely forgot all I've done in college, I guess I'll have to study it from the beginning now! The simmetric measure is a table in the output of SPSS, the same you can find in the link I've posted before.
However my point was to understand whether there was statistical significance, and apparently there is, amazing, I was so worried I had done all wrong with the choice of the variables :).
Thanks again!

Comment: Who asked you to perform an ANOVA? What question was that person hoping to answer via ANOVA?